# DirectShow Editing Services 4GB memory limit under Windows 7 x64

Tags: 64-bit, directshow, windows-7-x64, directshow.net

I compiled XTLTest as 64 bit and attempted to test some XTLs under windows 7 x64.

All these tests were done using an XTL with one clip from the WMV showcase, with a timeline sized at 1440x1080.

1. buffering set to 300 - plays back fine.
2. buffering set to 600 and got a cant run graph error.  Recompiled with large memory aware (which should be set by default on 64 bit apps), same thing.
3. Tested at 310 and worked fine.
4. Tried playing out 2 different instances of 64 bit XTLTest at the same time with 310 buffering, and the second one fails with 'can't run graph'.
5. buffering set to 80, was able to play 4 instances of XTLTest using a combined 4GB of memory. Execute any more instances and can't run graph.
6. Compiled .NET application targeted at any using DirectShowLib, and comfirmed its running as 64 bit native app. I was able to load 4 XTLs at 80 buffering until I got

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007000E): Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

So I can an only conclude that the DES subsystem has a 4GB memory limit for all applications combined.

Is this true? If so is this a DES limit or a DirectShow limit and is there any way to workaround?

best,
Tuviah Snyder
Lead programmer, MediaWan
Solid State Logic, Inc

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with DES directly before, but my impression has always been that it was deprecated quite a long time ago.  The COM objects that it is made up of are likely 32-bit.